# Calling jQuery plugin methods

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery, comparative-review

I have two code snippets and the following questions:

1. Which uses the best practice and why?
2. Which one is good for performance?

**Code 1**

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {

    // Responsive video
    var $area = $( "#sidebar" );
    $area.fitVids();

    // Image gallery
    var $slider = $( ".owl-carousel" );
    $slider.owlCarousel();

});
```

**Code 2**

```
// Global jQuery variable
var $ = jQuery;

/**
 * Responsive video
 */
var fitvidsInit = function() {
    var $area = $( "#sidebar" );
    $area.fitVids();
};

/**
 * Slides
 */
var sliderInit = function() {
    var $slider = $( ".owl-carousel" );
    $slider.owlCarousel();
};

/**
 * Execute code
 */
$( function() {
    fitvidsInit();
    sliderInit();
} )
```

I also have to defined the variable `$` because this is in WordPress.

Comment: You've already received an answer based on two code snippets.  Please don't modify them and add a new one.

Comment: Oh, why? Should I create new question? Because the third code are different.

Comment: I suppose, or you could wait for further reviews.  This one was up for just a day already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any performance difference would be too small to measure.

Code 2 pollutes the global namespace with three variables: `$`, `fitvidsInit`, and `sliderInit`.  Therefore, Code 1 is better.  I suggest eliminating `$area` and `$slider` as well:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {

    // Responsive video
    $( "#sidebar" ).fitVids();

    // Image gallery
    $( ".owl-carousel" ).owlCarousel();

});
```

Comment: Actually I've more code to see but I'll accept your answer. Your explanation are make sense for me